# Finding if a particle of a parametric equation is moving horizontally.

Tags: calculus

What I have worked out so far is if, but would like if someone would check if I made a mistake:

$$x=e^{3t}-2e^{-3t}$$
$$y=e^{3t}+5e^{-3t}$$

Then:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=3(e^{3t}-5e^{-3t})$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=3(e^{3t}+2e^{-3t})$$

So if I am looking for a particle that is moving horizontally then:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=0$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}\ne0$$

Checking  if $\frac{dy}{dt}=0$:

$$3(e^{3t}-5e^{-3t})=0$$
$$e^{3t}-5e^{-3t}=0$$
$$e^{3t}-\frac{5}{e^{3t}}=0$$
$$\frac{e^{6t}-5}{e^{3t}}=0$$

Denominator:

$$e^{3t}\ne0$$

Numerator:

$$e^{6t}-5=0$$
$$e^{6t}=5$$
$$t=\frac{ln(5)}{6}$$

Checking  if $\frac{dx}{dt}\ne0$:

Skipping head using the same concept as $\frac{dy}{dt}=0$ we get:

$$t=\frac{ln(-2)}{6}$$

which in turn means $t$ does not exist in the real number system.  My question is does a conclusion of DNE satisfy $\frac{dx}{dt}\ne0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, you need to check that $\frac{dx}{dt}\ne 0$ at the **particular** value of $t$ at which $\frac{dy}{dt}=0$.

However, $\frac{dx}{dt}=3(e^{3t}+2e^{-3t})$ is **never** $0$. That can be seen without trying to solve $3(e^{3t}+2e^{-3t})=0$, since $e^{3t}$ and $e^{-3t}$ are each always positive. But the fact that a solution of $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$ does not exist does imply that $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is never $0$, and in particular is not $0$ at $t=\frac{\ln 5}{6}$.

**Remark:** Before computing, it is a good idea to **look**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, certainly DNE means there is no solution in $t$ to $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = 0$, and hence, $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ cannot equal zero, ever, and so certainly not at $t = \dfrac{\ln 5}{6}$.

What we need here, given $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dy/dt}{dx/dt} = 0$$ with the denominator NOT equal to zero. And we've found it is not equal to zero (nor can it be). And that gives us $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac 0{dx/dt} = 0$$